# read the latest file from a directory using Oracle 11G sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have a source directory where everyday files come in .txt format. I have stored procedure which using `fgettr` reads the file with name `sr1_fl.txt`.

Due to this every time a file comes it has to be renamed.And after processing too it has to be renamed so that there is no error when the next file comes and its being renamed.

Is there any way that the latest file gets read from the directory?

Comment: Stored procedures are database specific and that can't be done in SQL. Please specify the exact flavour and version of your rdbms.

Comment: As Jakub mentioned in the comment above, you cannot do it in database. Think you will need to do it via Shell or batch script depending upon your OS.